# Using comma as list separator with StringTemplate 4

Tags: c#, stringtemplate-4

I need to create a comma-separated list of items:
    
       $subjects : {sub | $sub.Name$}separator=", "$
    
This does not seem to work. What is the right way to use a separator? 
Is there an alternative way to create a comma-separated list of items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format is:

> <multi-valued-attribute; separator=expr>

In your case it would be:

```
subjects: $subjects:{sub | $sub.name$}; separator=", "$
```

Which would render:

```
subjects: Maths, English
```

You can find out more from the [StringTemplate cheat sheet](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ST4/StringTemplate+cheat+sheet)